# Plotly sunburst sub-section custom color JavaScript

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm working with plotly in JS, trying to draw a sunburst chart. Everything works, but i would like to make it so that the child sections on the chart each have a different color. I cant seem to figure it out, any help is extremely appreciated.

Here is how my sunburst looks:

[image]

Notice that "Enos" and "Noam" have the same color, I would like them to have either different colors, or at least different opacities.

Like so:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
        var data = [{
            "type": "sunburst",
            "labels": ["Eve", "Awan", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Enoch"],
            "parents": ["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Awan"],
            "values": [100, 20, 80, 60, 20, 20]
        }];
        var layout = {
            sunburstcolorway: ["#636efa", "#ef553b"]
        };
        Plotly.newPlot('myChart', data, layout)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have custom colors for your traces, then you need to set the colors array of the marker object. There you can set the color for every single part of the sunburst diagram:

```
var data = [{
  "type": "sunburst",
  "labels": ["Eve", "Awan", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam","Enoch"],
  "parents": ["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Awan"],
  "values": [100, 20, 80, 60, 20, 20],
  "opacity" : 1,
  "marker": {
    colors: ["#ffffff","#fc6e08","#3e81ed","#3293e3","#c429ad","#d99543"] 
  }
}];

var layout = {
  // sunburstcolorway: ["#636efa", "#ef553b"]
};
      
Plotly.newPlot('myChart', data, layout)
```

So the first value ("Eve") has the first color of the array, the second value ("Awan")the second color, and so on. In the example, I set the opacity to 1 to get the real colors from the colors array.